# Ant doesn't pick up file modification when build

Tags: android, ant

I'm trying to build my android project from command line.

`ant debug install && adb shell 'am start -n com.test.example/.MainActivity'`

I find, `ant` doesn't recognise modified files sometimes(or most of times) unless I do `ant clean`

Is there a workaround to make ant recognise file changes while developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue:

```
ant clean
ant debug <-- This result is OK.
change some source code
ant debug

RESULT:
-dex:
[dex] No new compiled code. No need to convert bytecode to dalvik format.  
...
-package:
[apkbuilder] No changes. No need to create apk.
```

you can try a few things things:

- `Workaround for [dex]`: *include a `<delete>` just before the call to `<dex />` within the macro `"dex-helper"`:*

> `<delete file="${intermediate.dex.file}"/>`

- `Workaround for [apkbuilder]`: *include a `<delete>` into the macro `"package-helper"`:*

> `<macrodef name="package-helper">
>     <element name="extra-jars" optional="yes" />
>     <sequential>
>       <delete failonerror="false" file="${out.packaged.file}"/>
>       <apkbuilder outfolder="${out.abs.dir}" resourcefile="${res.pkg.file.name}"
>
>        ...`

See [**HERE**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22948) for these *Workarounds* and a long, related, discussion.

these may be useful too:

- try `ant clean debug`: *call clean, because otherwise the build system will not detect changes in the configuration, and may not recompile the proper classes.* , OR
- `android update project -p <project-path>`: *will generate any files and folders that are either missing or need to be updated, as needed for the Android project* See [**HERE**](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject)

Comment: Does gradle suffer from the same problem (not catching the file modficiation)?